# vertical line javascript trouble

Tags: javascript, line

```
document.write(new String("abgigi").search("|"));
```

The code above displays 0 instead of the expected -1. Why is that so?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`search` takes a regular expression as its argument and `|` is the OR operator in regex: your search pattern is essentially "an empty string OR an empty string", so a match is found at position 0.

If you want to do a simple string match, use `indexOf` instead of `search`.

Comment: I found that escaping the string that I'm searching for disabled the regular expressions. Also thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: @Andrei Busuioc: Yes, that will work as well, but if you don't require a regular expression, `indexOf` will save the overhead of parsing your string as a regular expression.